# contact-form human readable E-Mail template

Tags: plugin-contactform, plugin-contactformextensions

I use [contact-form plugin](https://github.com/craftcms/contact-form) together with [contact-form-extensions](https://github.com/hybridinteractive/craft-contact-form-extensions) to create a human-readable E-Mail.

I've gotten so far:

```
------ <br>
<p>
{{ submission.fromName }} <br>
{{ submission.message['firstName'] }} {{ submission.message['lastName'] }} <br>
{{ submission.message['shippingaddress'] }} <br>
{{ submission.message['zip'] }}{{ submission.message['city'] }}
</p>
------ <br>
<p>
{% for submission in craft.contactFormExtensions.submissions %}
   {% if loop.first %}
      Bestelldatum: {{ submission.dateCreated|date('d-m-Y H:i') }}<br>
   {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
E-Mail: <a href="mailto:{{ submission.fromEmail }}">{{ submission.fromEmail }}</a> <br>
Telefon: <a href="tel:{{ submission.message['tel'] }}">{{ submission.message['tel'] }}</a> <br>
Nachricht: {{ submission.message['body'] }}</p>
</p>
------ <br>
<p>Produkte:</p>

{% for submission in craft.contactFormExtensions.submissions %}
   {% if loop.first %}
      {{ submission.message }}
   {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

This works and results in this E-Mail:

[image]

Question 1: As you can see the last for loop is formatted somewhat like a JSON array. How can I stop that from happening?

Question 2: Since some of the fields are already printed as a separate tag, is it possible to exclude those fields from the last for loop? Because all custom fields are packed into `message[custom]` the normal twig tags don't seem to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What are you trying to output with the last loop in your template?

With `craft.contactFormExtensions.submissions` you're iterating through *submissions*, not fields of a single submission. In the e-mail template, you already have access to the current submission through the `submission` variable, you don't need to go through `craft.contactFormExtensions.submissions`. Looks like this is intended to show a [list of submissions](https://github.com/hybridinteractive/craft-contact-form-extensions#display-form-submissions-in-your-template-files) (for example, in an admin view of submissions in the frontend).

> Question 1: As you can see the last for loop is formatted somewhat like a JSON array. How can I stop that from happening?

Since your submission consists of several fields, `submission.message` is an associative array with field values. You output that directly, triggering the `__toString` method of the value object. This just prints a JSON string, since it's the only reasonable thing to do in this case.

> Question 2: Since some of the fields are already printed as a separate tag, is it possible to exclude those fields from the last for loop? Because all custom fields are packed into message[custom] the normal twig tags don't seem to work.

Why are you looping through the fields again if you already output all fields above? Looks like you're trying to loop through a specific field in the submission (`Produkte`), so you'll need something like `submission.message.products` (replace the last part with the name of the field in your contact form template).

If you want to display some hardcoded fields at the top and then display all other fields in a list, you can use the [`filter` filter](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/filters/filter.html) to exclude some fields from the loop:

```twig
{% set excludedFields = ['firstName', 'shippingAddress', 'zip'] %}
{% for field in submission.message|filter((_, field) => field not in excludedFields) %}
    {{ field }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Fantastic. Besides the hardcoded fields I have a loop which creates non hardcoded select fields inside the contact form. So I cant just hardcode everything. I'll try it out.

Comment: @KSPR Yeah, in this case the last code example is probably what you're looking for. By the way, you can also invert the logic if you want to specify an include list instead of an exclude list for the fields to display. Just use `in` instead of `not in` in this case, then you only need to specify the fields you want to display. Whichever is easier.